# Create a date column and assign value from a condition based on an existing date column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I have the following:

```
import pandas as pd

    file = pd.DataFrame()
    
        file['CASH RECIEVED DATE'] = ['2018-07-23', '2019-09-26', '2017-05-02']
```

and I need to create a column called `Cash Received Date`

```
file['Cash Received Date']
```

such as if `[CASH_RECIEVED_DATE]` is not null && `[CASH RECIEVED_DATE]` <= 2022-09-01 then `[Cash Received Date]` will be `2019-09-01`, otherwise it will be the value of `[CASH_RECIEVED_DATE]`, so the output would be:

```
    file['Cash Received Date'] = ['2019-09-01', '2019-09-26', '2019-09-01']
```

How do I achieve this by creating a function?

Many thanks,
Rafa

Comment: please add your input & target output as text

Comment: Sorry I'm new on this, I hope I've improved my comments.

Comment: I can't see your input data, please add your dataframe and a target example, you can copy it directly into the body of your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def compare_date(x):
    if pd.to_datetime(x) > pd.to_datetime('2019-09-01'):
        return pd.to_datetime(x)
    else:
        return pd.to_datetime('2019-09-01')

file['Cash Received Date'] = file['CASH RECIEVED DATE'].apply(lambda x: compare_date(x))
```

gives `file` as :

```
  CASH RECIEVED DATE Cash Received Date
0         2018-07-23         2019-09-01
1         2019-09-26         2019-09-26
2         2017-05-02         2019-09-01
```

P.S. It's best practice to give columns and dataframes more distinct names so as to prevent confusion with very similar or vague variable/column names.

Comment: Do you know how to include another conditional that says if ['Policy'] (a column already included in file) is X then change dates as per above, otherwise just copy the ['CASH RECIEVED DATE']?

Answer (score 0):

using `.mask`

first step is to ensure your values are datetime values.

```
df['Cash Received Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Cash Received Date'])

df['new_date'] = df['Cash Received Date'].mask(
                  df['Cash Received Date'].dropna().le('2019-09-01'),'2019-01-01')

  Cash Received Date    new_date
0         2019-09-01  2019-01-01
1         2019-09-26  2019-09-26
2         2019-09-01  2019-01-01
```